# Stop Sum at certain number Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Im creating a google spreadsheet document and im counting hours, im currently using this formula:

=MAX(J5-96, 0 )

And it gives me 0 instead of negative numbers, every time the number is greater than 96 it adds up a number but I want to stop this number at number 18, that way when I gets to the number 18 it stops in that number and it doesn't count any other number.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
=MIN(MAX(J5-96, 0 ),18)
```